# FOS User Bundle: access other user profile: "This user does not have access to this section."

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to set up a simple action for a member details of other members of the website; my controller look like that at the moment:

```
public function modalProfileAction($id) {
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }
    return $this->render('TESTUserBundle:Profile:modal_short_profile.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user
    ));
}
```

This action is triggered by a JS (AJAX method GET). My routing is:

```
TEST_user_modal:
    pattern: /team-member/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: TESTUserBundle:User:modalProfile }
    methods:  [GET]
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

I am geeting the follwong error: "This user does not have access to this section."
Is there a way I could get around that? Am I using the wrong method or there is a security issue I should include?
Ideas will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)if you want to get current logged in user , you must use this code to get user data:

```
$current_user=$this->getUser();
```

for example if you want to get id and username of current user can use this:

```
$id=$current_user->getId();
$username=$current_user->getUsername();
```

2) if you want to get another user information in your admin panel , you must use repository to get informations:

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

    if (!$entity)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
    }



    return $this->render('UserBundle:User:show.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
    ));
}
```

I hope this help U!

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of lost on what you're asking but reading your logic also confuses me a bit as well.

My interpretation of what you're doing is:

- Sending a request to retrieve a user based of user id.
- Using FOSUserBundle to retrieve information on the user.
- Validating that the retrieved information is an instance of the User class.
- Returning the user information.

My question is why are you validating if the returned object FROM THE USER MANAGER is an instance of user?  Are you instead trying to validate that the request is from a valid logged in user with proper permissions?  If so then you aren't doing that at all.

2 Solutions I see are:

**Don't validate logged in user.**

1. Send a request to retrieve a user via the users id.
2. Retrieve information using the user manager.
3. Return information.

**Validate user is logged in before returning information**

1. Send a request to retrieve a user via the user id.
2. Validate the request is coming from a user that is logged in and has proper permissions.
3. Retrieve information using the user manager
4. Return information.

Validating a user is:

```
public function modalProfileAction($id) {
    $users = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($users) || $users instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('You must be logged in to view this information.');
    }
    $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

    return $this->render('TESTUserBundle:Profile:modal_short_profile.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user
    ));
}
```